# Boost как правельно получать в асинхронном клиенте WS сообщения с сервера?

Tags: c++, boost

у меня есть пример из boost который отлично работает — это пример асинхронного WS клиента. Но я не могу ни как разобраться с этой самой асинхронностью,
я хочу подключится к WS серверу, и после чего вернуть управление в основной поток, а данные которые присылает мне WS сервер класть в переменную что бы можно было их читать например в цикле. Данные из себя представляют строку переменной длины обычно пару тройку килобайт. Собственно прошу показать как это сделать, с синхронным клиентом все просто и понятно, а вот тут вот совсем не понятно… :(
Когда я вызываю ioc.run() - он запускает асинхроный цикл обработки событий — но это еще и является точкой выхода из приложения, то есть когда он завершён я уже не могу получить ни каких данных. %) во общем очень не понятно… Может кто ни буть накидать на коленки пример кода, он не обязательно должен работать, хотя бы приблизительно как это будет выглядеть, я дальше сам додумаю уже.

```
#include "libs/beast/example/common/root_certificates.hpp"
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
 
namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;       // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
// Report a failure
void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}
 
// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    websocket::stream<
        beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>> ws_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
    std::string host_;
    std::string text_;
 
public:
    // Resolver and socket require an io_context
    explicit
        session(net::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx)
        : resolver_(net::make_strand(ioc))
        , ws_(net::make_strand(ioc), ctx)
    {
    }
 
    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void run(
            char const* host,
            char const* port,
            char const* text)
    {
        // Save these for later
        host_ = host;
        text_ = text;
 
        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(host,port,beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_resolve,shared_from_this()));
    }
 
    void on_resolve(beast::error_code ec,tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if (ec) return fail(ec, "resolve");
        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(results,beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_connect,shared_from_this()));
    }
 
    void on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type ep)
    {
        if (ec) return fail(ec, "connect");
 
        // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
        // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
        // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
        host_ += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());
        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
 
        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(
            ws_.next_layer().native_handle(),
            host_.c_str()))
        {
            ec = beast::error_code(static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()),
                net::error::get_ssl_category());
            return fail(ec, "connect");
        }
 
        // Perform the SSL handshake
        ws_.next_layer().async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::client,beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_ssl_handshake,shared_from_this()));
    }
 
    void on_ssl_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec) return fail(ec, "ssl_handshake");
 
        // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
        // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();
 
        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
            websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                beast::role_type::client));
 
        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::request_type& req)
            {
                req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                    " websocket-client-async-ssl");
            }));
 
        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/", beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_handshake,shared_from_this()));
    }
 
    void on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec) return fail(ec, "handshake");
        // Send the message
        ws_.async_write(net::buffer(text_),beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write,shared_from_this()));
    }
 
    void on_write(beast::error_code ec,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
 
        if (ec) return fail(ec, "write");
 
        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(buffer_,beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read,shared_from_this()));
    }
 
    void on_read(beast::error_code ec,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
 
        if (ec) return fail(ec, "read");
 
        // Close the WebSocket connection
        ws_.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal,beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_close,shared_from_this()));
    }
 
    void on_close(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec)  return fail(ec, "close");
        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
        // The make_printable() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer_.data()) << std::endl;
    }
};
 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        std::cerr <<
            "Usage: websocket-client-async-ssl <host> <port> <text>\n" <<
            "Example:\n" <<
            "    websocket-client-async-ssl echo.websocket.org 443 \"Hello, world!\"\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto const host = argv[1];
    auto const port = argv[2];
    auto const text = argv[3];
 
    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;
 
    // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
    ssl::context ctx{ ssl::context::tlsv12_client };
 
    // This holds the root certificate used for verification
    load_root_certificates(ctx);
 
    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    std::make_shared<session>(ioc, ctx)->run(host, port, text);
 
    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the socket is closed.
    ioc.run();
 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Цикл обработки событий можно запускать и на одну итерацию `io_context::run_one`, и в течении определенного времени `io_context::run_until`, и для разбора накопившихся событий `io_context::poll`.
Далее, метод `io_context::run` не является точкой входа ни в каком смысле. Его можно прервать вызовом `io_context::stop`, а потом запустить еще раз, предварительно возобновив вызовом `io_context::restart`.

Comment: Млин - я ошибаюсь или для конкретного кода я должен сделать 3 разных обработчика событий? для соединения, для обработки данных, и для закрытия соединения? потому что сейчас когда я вызываю run_one выполняется весь код, и даже если я явно не закрываю соединение с WS оно закрывается само (не по таймауту)

Comment: @stasstas Хм, у меня ощущение, что вчера я отвечал на какой-то другой вопрос, во всяком случае примера я не помню... Но в этом примере нет `run_one`, а соединение закрывается явно или по таймауту.

Comment: А обработчиков в реальном коде могут быть десятки и сотни.